# How to validate action on website by vba?

Tags: html, vba, validation, internet-explorer

In an attempt to mark a checkbox in a website, I let vba open the site in ie. However even though the checkbox shows as being marked, I noticed the difference between when I let VBA do it, and manually clicked myself is that the `class` of the element changes to "dirty.." instead of "pristine.." after clicking.

Without that change to "dirty.." and touched, the website does not register the action as actually performed.

So I tried to set the properties of the "dirty..." class to checked, but it did not register the action as performed, So I want to compare all the properties of the "dirty.." and "pristine.." class, to see if I can make it register the action as performed by changing all the expressions required to make it dirty.

Hence, I made a manual comparison of the elemnt code before and after clicking by a manual user, and it is located in the vba code below as the first comments.

```
'Difference in html element code between vba clicking the checkbox and an actual user clicking the checkbox:
'<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">
'<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">
'<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="permission" type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.checked">
'<input class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" id="permission" type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.checked">

Set elements1a = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse")
MsgBox (elementa1a)
For Each Item In elements1a
    If elements1a.Item.Checked = False Then
        elements1a.Item.Click
        If elements1a.Item.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox ("clicking the checkbox switched the checked-ness of the item to true")
        End If
    End If
    If elements1a.Item.complete = False Then
        elements1a.Item.Click
        If elements1a.Item.complete = True Then
            MsgBox ("clicking the checkbox switched the completeness of the item to true")
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox (elements1a.Item.className & " and " & elements1a.Item.Checked)
    If elements1a.Item.className = "ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" Then
        elements1a.Item.Checked = True
        MsgBox (elements1a.Item.Checked)
        'Element code when vba clicks the button:
        '<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-parse ng-pristine" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">
        'Element code when an actual user actually clicks the button
        '<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-parse ng-dirty" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">
    End If
Next

'the vba command for the not user-clicked checkbox
Set elements1b = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")
    MsgBox (element1b)
    For Each Item In elements1b
        If elements1b.Item.className = "ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" Then
            elements1b.Item.Checked = True
            MsgBox (elements1b.Item.Checked)
            '<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-parse ng-pristine" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">
            '<form name="forms.addressContract" class="form __hor ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-pattern ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-parse ng-dirty" novalidate="" ng-class="{'force-show-errors': isSubmitted}" ng-submit="submitAddress()">

        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those stumbling upon the same problem, this did the trick:

```
'1. Mark checkbox
    'MsgBox ("engage filling")
    Set elements1e = ie.document.getElementById("permission")
    'MsgBox (elements1e.Name & " " & elements1e.className & elements1e.placeholder)
    elements1e.Focus
    elements1e.Click
'    MsgBox ("cLICKED")
```

I am not sure why it is possible to `.focus` and `.click` on this element and not on others. I think it has to do with the type of object it is within the html code of the site itself.